# Watchguard VPN Connection Issue

Tags: vpn, watchguard

I am having problems setting up a BOVPN between an XTM510 and an XTM21-w.

I have checked over the settings 3 times for all of the phases, tunnels and gateways on both sides and everything is correct.

I checked the log files and did a search VPN and saw the following messages...

Debug   2015-06-24T18:50:16 Process=sslvpn  msg=Certificates are not yet generated,Generate Ceritificates

Debug   2015-06-24T18:50:01 Process=iked  msg=Livesecurity feature
missing, please import feature key to enable BOVPN and MUVPN

Debug   2015-06-24T18:50:01 Process=iked  msg=changed_xpath[1] : +/profile/system-parameters/vpn-global-setting

but under System/Feature Key (using the web interface), it shows that I have 5 BO VPN licenses that never expire. I haven't added the WG to my watchguard account online (Bought the W-21 used and it is still registered to the previous Owner - I have sent them an email) but I thought if this was the issue, it would tell me with a message like the Wireless Setup page does.

**Edit - I checked the diagnostic reports for each side of the VPN and noticed something different between the 2 sides but I am unsure of what it means..

The one side has the following...

[Run-time Info (gateway IKE_SA)]
    Name: "A to B" (IfStatus: 0x80000001)

but the other side has...

[Run-time Info (gateway IKE_SA)]
    Name: "B to A" (IfStatus: 0x80000000)

Please Help!

Thanks,

Stan

Comment: If you do in fact have the required Feature Key and the error is related to the Feature Key then your best course of action is to open a support case with Watchguard.

Comment: No feature key or response back from Watchguard as of yet, still not sure if that's the issue